# VB CSS Trouble Div autosize

Tags: html, css, vb.net

Hello trying to get my website to display correctly having trouble. I am using CSS and it looks completely different in firefox compared to IE however neither do what i need it to do.

I have vb validators that when something is not inputed in the the textboxes it displays label messages that you need to input something. But my main div is not expanding when they click the submit button and the labels appear they just appear under the footer and out the bottom of the webpage.

```
body  
{
    /*font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;*/
    background: #42413C;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: -moz-center;
}

#container
    {
        width: 1024px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        margin: 0px auto 0px auto;

    }

#topbanner
   {
       width: 100%;
       height: 75px;
       background: #ADB96E;
       color: #FFFFFF;
       text-align: center;
       font-size: 40px;
   }
    #maincontent
    {

        width: 780px;
        padding:5px 0;
        float:right;

    }

    #menunav
    {
        float:left;
        width:180px;
        background: #EADCAE;
        padding-bottom: 10px;


    }
    #footer
    {
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #ccc49f;
        position: relative;
        padding:10px 0;
        clear:both;

    }
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you first included a CSS reset? You can find more information right here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: /*because of different browser should 0 padding out */
    ul,ol,dl{
    padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
    }
    
    h1,h2,p
    {
        margin-top:0;
        padding-left:15px;
        
    }
   
   /* This removes blue borders around some images in certain browsers */
    a img
    {
        border:none;
    }

Comment: Ok. Why exactly are you using VB.net for checking your input, and not JavaScript (ie. jQuery)?

Comment: but in my situation as of right now I only have 5 divs I can not get that to display correctly i have a div for each of my css ids then i use a masterpage to keep the layout the same but i can not get the css layout to work the way i need it too

Comment: because I know vb i dont know javascript and visual studios offers validation tools I am sure there is a million ways to do validation but I wanted to figure my css issue out

Comment: I can't really help you with that little code-snippet. Is it possible to upload your problem on jsfiddle?

Comment: What I can see on jsfiddle isn't that bad, it doesn't look "wrong"? http://i56.tinypic.com/10zae5y.jpg. But the VB code doesn't work. I think it's better to build your website using HTML/CSS and using JS (jQuery) to check your input instead of ASP/VB.net.

Comment: But trying to figure out how to get my maincontent area to autosize depending on how much content is displayed and also have my leftnavigation autosize with it.

Comment: As of right now it will autosize when the page first loads but when i add more content dynamically and the page refreshes it stays that size even though there is more content

Comment: That could be because your elements are floating. Try using overflow: hidden; in the element where they have to "stack in". (In this case on #maincontent)

Comment: i tried overflow: auto; but never tried hidden thanks for your help